# What do I need to do to be notified of any urgent security issues with Joomla?

Tags: joomla-3.x, security

Is there a mailing list somewhere specifically for this? None of the [mailing lists on the official Joomla site](https://www.joomla.org/mailing-lists.html) seem to mention that.

In my case, I just have one Joomla site to look after, so I'm only interested in particularly important emails such as security issues, and don't want to have to manually filter those out from others that aren't of interest.

Comment: the upcoming J3.5 version (expected to arrive really soon) will include a feature for admin notification emails on core updates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Joomla has a section of the developer site called the "[Security Centre](https://developer.joomla.org/security-centre.html)" which sends out emails about security issues. There is also a mailing list for the same content. There doesn't seem to be a link to it any more but you can subscribe at:

http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify?uri=JoomlaSecurityNews

There is a feature in development/about to be released [in 3.5 that will notify Joomla administrators](https://www.joomla.org/announcements/release-news/5645-joomla-3-5-beta-2-released-2.html) of updates to the Joomla core.

So, assuming you keep uptodate then the 3.5 release should help.

Answer (score 3):

By being RSS die-hard fan for 15+ years, I have collected few security feeds I use daily in my Outlook:

**Joomla Security RSS**

Joomla Security Announcements / Original Joomla.org Security Centre (superseded by JDN)
http://feeds.joomla.org/JoomlaSecurityNews?format=xml

Joomla Security Centre JDN / Joomla Developer Network Security Centre
https://developer.joomla.org/security-centre.feed?type=rss

Joomla VEL Blog / Joomla Vulnerable Extensions Blog
http://vel.joomla.org/articles?format=feed&type=rss

Joomla VEL Live / Live VEL
http://vel.joomla.org/live-vel?format=feed&type=rss

Joomla VEL Resolved / Resolved VEL
http://vel.joomla.org/resolved?format=feed&type=rss

Joomla EOL SecFix / Security hotfixes for Joomla EOL versions - Revision history
https://docs.joomla.org/index.php?title=Security_hotfixes_for_Joomla_EOL_versions&feed=atom&action=history

**General Security RSS**

Sucuri Blog / Sucuri Blog
http://blog.sucuri.net/feed

Symantec Security / Symantec Connect Security Response - Blog Entries
http://www.symantec.com/connect/item-feeds/blog/2261/feed/all/en/all

Malwarebytes Unpacked / Malwarebytes Unpacked Blog
http://blog.malwarebytes.org/feed/

AppCheck-NG Alerts / AppCheck-NG » Advisories & Alerts
http://appcheck-ng.com/category/category-3/feed/

Computer Security News / Topix Computer Security News
http://www.topix.com/rss/tech/computer-security

Detectify / Detectify Blog
http://blog.detectify.com/rss

ESET Blog / We Live Security » Languages » English
http://feeds.feedburner.com/eset/blog?format=xml

Fox-IT Intl Blog / Fox-IT International blog
http://blog.fox-it.com/feed/

Hacker News / The Hacker News
http://feeds.feedburner.com/theHackerNews_com?format=xml

HackRead News / HackRead
http://hackread.com/feed/

HOTforSecurity / HOTforSecurity Blog
http://feeds.feedburner.com/HOTforSecurity

**My Twitter List SECURITY**

Appcheck NG @AppcheckNG
Bradley Deacon @BradleyWDeacon
CrowdShield @crowdshield
Detectify @detectify
Dr. Angela Orebaugh @AngelaOrebaugh
ESET @ESET
HackRead @HackRead
Joomlavel @JoomlaVel
JP Vergne @PirateOrg
Malwarebytes @Malwarebytes
Martin Brinkmann @ghacks
SpiderLabs @SpiderLabs
Sucuri @sucurisecurity
The Hacker News @TheHackersNews

I hope you will find this information useful... :-)

Comment: Don't mention it man... Got few more hundreds where that came from ;-)

Comment: That's some great list you got there! Thanx a lot, and also for assuring me I'm not the Last RSS Mohican on this world....

Comment: I hear you man... It's such a shame that RSS support is dropping left and right... Even here on JSE or any other SX site, one can't have a decent feed of his own activity, favorites, reputation changes, etc... {sigh}